# Why does doing math in spotlight use extreme high amounts of CPU + memory?

Tags: macos, memory, spotlight, performance

I often use Spotlight as a easy access calculator but recently I noticed that doing so consumes an EXTREMELY large amount of CPU and memory, as seen in the spotlight process `corespotlightd`. Basically it uses all available ram, 19GB in the screenshots below, and 762% of the CPU.

I'm on the latest macOS as of this posting (September 2021, Big Sur 11.6).

Does anyone know why this might be? Is it just a performance bug of some kind?

### corespotlightd using 762.0% of CPU

[image: Spotlight using 762.0% of CPU]

### corespotlightd using 19.37GB of memory

[image: Spotlight using 19.37GB of ram]

Comment: I am on MBP 15" 2017 and cannot reproduce this issue with that exact calculation and macOS 11.6. What steps to solve this problem have you tried so far? I.e. restarting, booting in safe mode, killing spotlight,...?

Comment: Hi, do you have iOS Simulator open when spotlight use high amount of CPU ?

Comment: @p-mercier No. It is reproducible even without the iOS Sim open.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Ventura 13.2.

Comment: I hate this too. I use Spotlight not only as a convenient calculator, but also as a second clipboard or temporary scratchpad for notes. All these usages make the computer burning hot and loud.

Comment: I think typing a lot, or for a long time, into spotlight is what makes it use so much CPU and memory.

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me very often since I frequently use Spotlight for math. I've tried every suggestion and have found no solution, other than killing `corespotlightd`.

Here's a script I now use to handle this:

```
#!/bin/zsh -u

process="corespotlightd"
curr_cpu=`ps -Ao pcpu,comm | grep -i $process | sort -nr | grep -v grep | head -1 | awk '{print int($1)}'`

if [[ $curr_cpu -ge 100 ]]; then
  osascript -e 'display notification "'"Killed at $curr_cpu%"'" with title "'"High CPU: $process"'"'
  pkill -9 $process
  exit
fi
```

Setup a launch daemon (I use LaunchControl) or a cron job, and call this script once every 1-5 minutes or more.

Comment: Will this also make Spotlight faster? Spotlight used to be extremely fast at fetching file searches, but lately it's been extremely slow. Strangely though, when performing a file search within the Finder Search bar, it fetches results almost instantly. I am on macOS Big Sur on my 2013 MacBook Pro 15" Retina. Note, the computer is still fine, had a logic board (RAM, CPU, GPU) replaced in 2019, and the SSD wearability health  is still above 80% (I don't save a lot on the SSD!), so it is not at risk of failing any time soon.

Comment: @AVelj This script can be used to kill corespotlightd if it gets stuck at high cpu for a period of time. I never had issues with Spotlight itself even when corespotlightd was at 600%, but my computer would get hot and the fans would max out.

Comment: Cheers, will bookmark this solution for when I notice corespotlightd running crazy! My main issue is that spotlight has been very laggy lately. I wonder if having recently installed Alfred (but still never used it) had something to do with it? Thanks :)